# Text classification + Naive Bayes + Python : Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I am trying to do text classification with Naive Bayes. This is my code:

```
#splitting Pandas dataframe into train set and test set

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data['description'], data['category_id'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#production of bag of words from x_train

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
x_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
train_vocab = count_vect.get_feature_names()

#training the Naive Bayes classifier

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(x_train_counts, y_train)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-0cb3dc7193bf> in <module>()
      1 #training the Naive Bayes classifier
      2 
----> 3 clf = MultinomialNB().fit(x_train_counts, y_train)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    577             Returns self.
    578         """
--> 579         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
    580         _, n_features = X.shape
    581 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    577     else:
    578         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 579         _assert_all_finite(y)
    580     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':
    581         y = y.astype(np.float64)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X)
     42             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     43         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 44                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     45 
     46 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

The type of x_train_counts is scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix.

```
print(type(x_train_counts))
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

The type of y_train is pandas.core.series.Series.

```
print(type(y_train))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using? I supposed it's something like <= **0.16.1**, since the last version **0.20.0**, has a `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` instead of the `cross_validation.train_test_split` you're using. What are the types of `data['description']` and `data['category_id']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is related to your `data['description']` and `data['category_id']`. Is the first one something like an array with **n** elements comprising of texts and the second another array like object also with **n** elements consisting of labels for for the first, e.g, `['0', '1', '3', ...]`?

As a test, only by replacing your data with some sklearn dataset would produce a correct run:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian',
               'comp.graphics', 'sci.med']

dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
     categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(dataset.data, dataset.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#production of bag of words from x_train

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
x_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
train_vocab = count_vect.get_feature_names()

#training the Naive Bayes classifier

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(x_train_counts, y_train)
```

Try to test that out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: There were NaNs in category_id column. I cleaned those rows. Now it's working.

Comment: So it had to do with what I suspected, right? Did my answer help anyhow?

Comment: Helped to some extent. Anyway, I've chosen it as accepted answer.

Comment: Great! The most important part is that you solved your issue :D

Answer (score 1):

Before train_test_split or generating test and train sets from featurization to fit for the model, the best  practice is to use the following command

> > dataframe_name.isnull().any()
> >     this will give the column names and True if atleast one Nan value is present
> >
> > dataframe_name.isnull().sum()
> >     this will give the column names and value of how many NaN values are present

This will not create the problem of NaN.